# Show that the following logical implication is True?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

[image]

It is True, I did the truth tables... but it's just hard to prove it. I tried simplifying both sides but still it wasn't a match?

Comment: If you did the truth tables, then you proved it.  Unless you are restricting yourself to something like constructive logic.

Comment: No the question asks us to prove it logically (make it look like another)

Comment: Similar to how you prove a trig identity

Comment: It's ambiguous whether you mean $a \iff (b \implies c)$ or $(a \iff b) \implies c$.

Comment: The $$\iff$$ is what splits the equation. On the left we have the x $\land$ .. and the right we have the (($x \to y) ... \to (x \land .. )$

Comment: Did you try to put both sides in disjunctive normal form? It doesn't look too hard. If it didn't work, edit the question to show the steps of your attempt, and maybe someone will spot where you went wrong.

Comment: What is "disjunctive normal form"

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DisjunctiveNormalForm.html ... abbreviated DNF. It's basically a truth table in the guise of a logic formula. Note that the fourth line of the posted answer has the expression in DNF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
((x\to y)\lor\lnot z)\to(x\land \lnot(y \to z)) 
&\equiv \lnot((x\to y)\lor\lnot z)\lor (x\land \lnot(y \to z)) \\
&\equiv \lnot( \lnot x\lor y \lor\lnot z)\lor (x\land \lnot(\lnot y \lor z))\\
&\equiv (x\land \lnot y\land z)\lor (x\land ( y \land \lnot z))\\
&\equiv (x\land \lnot y \land z) \lor (x\land y \land \lnot z)\\
&\equiv x\land ((\lnot y \land z) \lor (y \land \lnot z))\\
&\equiv x\land ((\lnot y \leftrightarrow z)\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: How does the fifth step simplify to the sixth (last)

Comment: Booleans are only two valued,  so $ (a \land b) \lor (\lnot a \land \lnot b) \equiv (a \leftrightarrow b)$